# Laravel 5.7 Invalid argument supplied for foreach() when looping in controller

Tags: php, laravel, file

When I try to do a loop inside my controller, I get the error `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()` and I can't really figure out why. I have a `form` where it is supposed to be possible to upload multiple files

Here is what I got so far:

```
use App\SingleApplication;
use App\SingleApplicationFile;

$application = SingleApplication::create([
   'email' => request()->email,
   'name' => request()->name,
    ...// more fields
]);

$allowedfileExtension = ['pdf', 'jpg', 'png', 'docx'];
$files = request()->has('attachment');
if ($files) {
     foreach ($files as $file) {
       $filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
       $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
       $filesize = $file->getSize();
       $check = in_array($extension, $allowedfileExtension);

       if ($check) {

         foreach ($file as $att) {
         $filename = Storage::disk('local')->put('attachments', request()->file($att));
          SingleApplicationFile::create([
             'files_id' => $application->id,
             'single_application_id' => $application->id,
             'attachment' => $filename,
             'attachment_name' => $extension,
             'attachment_size' => $filesize,
          ]);
        }
     }
  }
}
```

So, what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a boolean

```
$files = request()->hasFile('attachment'); // return  if has file not array of files
```

You should get files as

```
$files = request()->file('attachment'); // returns array of files
```

Or you can change condition as

```
$hasfiles = request()->hasFile('attachment');

if ($hasfiles) {

    $files = request()->file('attachment');
    // your rest code
```

> Note: File Checking should be done with hasFile because file and other
>   fields are different.

Here is the reference [link](https://laraveldaily.com/requests-has-and-hasfile/).